# my imageview not align on left of edittextfield

Tags: android, android-layout

below is my xml code my imageview not show on left of edittext any idea why??????  right side imageview will be show but left side imageview not visible on screen

```
       <RelativeLayout 

android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >


     <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"



 android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />


<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"

    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" >

</EditText>
 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText1"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
```

Comment: For first ImageView there is not EditText with id editText1 and for second ImageView android:layout_alignTop="@+id/editText1"
 android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText1"  both you cant give. *remove align bottom*

Comment: look at @tsp answer, your EditText is taking your whole screen size, so your ImageView is probably hidden below your EditText.

Comment: please ediy my relative layout i want  imageview edittext imageview in 1 row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
<RelativeLayout 
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

     <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
     <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
```

Comment: i s help but left imageview show inside edittest i want left imageview show left of edittex t not inside edittext

Comment: firstimageview show inside edittext i want to show left of edittext

Answer (score 1):

```
       <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" 
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        >
    </EditText>
```

---

```
  <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/editText1"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: when i did wrap on edoittext width its goes right of screen please set my whole relative layout

Answer (score 0):

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:padding="5dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
     >
</EditText>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
```